# Выбрать контейнер для реализации сортировки java

Tags: java, сортировка

Пишу программу, где мне необходимы контейнеры чисел, которые нужно отсортировать по возрастанию. Я думаю, взять ли мне обычный java массив или коллекцию ArrayList. В классах соответственно Arrays и Collections есть функции Arrays.sort и Collections.sort. Подскажите, есть ли какие-то различия, какую из этих функций использовать? Различается ли время выполнения сортировки массива от времени сортировки ArrayList'a соответствующими функциями?

Answer (score 1):

Если числа будут вставляться редко и уникальны то лучше всего treeset, тогда сразу будет все осортировано.
И да ответ время различается в collections.sort еще нужно передать компаратор или объекты хранимые в коллекции должны имплементить compareTo, но в случае с числами разницы думаю нет

Comment: С числами разница есть, смотрите мой ответ ниже, Arrays.sort  и Collections.sort() могут отличаться

Answer (score 1):

Короткий ответ, **да отличаются и могут очень сильно** если испльзовать Collections.sort() и Arrays.sort(), две эти функции  используют разные алгоритмы. Во всем остальном ArrayList это массив и если использовать одинаковый алгоритм, то скорость сортировки будет одинакова. 
Более детально смотрите ниже.

Все достаточно просто, сортировку свою писать никто не будет, все будут использовать готовую реализацию, так что возьмут или Collections.sort() и Arrays.sort(), для сортировки коллекций и массивов соответственно. Если посмотреть в реализацию метода Collections.sort()

```
  public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void sort(List<T> list) {
    list.sort(null);
  }
```

то видно, что вызывается лист сорт. 
Дефолтная реализация сортировке в листе, работает медленно, так как там есть дополнительное копирование и переприсваивание.

```
default void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    Object[] a = this.toArray();
    Arrays.sort(a, (Comparator) c);
    ListIterator<E> i = this.listIterator();
    for (Object e : a) {
        i.next();
        i.set((E) e);
    }
}
```

Но если заглянуть в реализацию сортировки для ArrayList, то можно обнаружить, что там находится такой код

```
public void sort(Comparator<? super E> c) {
    final int expectedModCount = modCount;
    Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);
    if (modCount != expectedModCount) {
        throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
    modCount++;
}
```

и может показаться, что этот код работает так же, о если заглянуть в **Arrays.sort((E[]) elementData, 0, size, c);**, то окажется, что там находится TeamSort. Если посмотреть в реализацию сортировки для массива, то там окажется ДуалКвикСорт.

Больше информации об отличии двух алгоритмов можно найти [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20917617/whats-the-difference-of-dual-pivot-quick-sort-and-quick-sort)

Answer (score 0):

1.Разница между ArrayList и обычным массивом. Здесь все просто. Поскольку  ArrayList  инкапсулирует обычный массив, то и разницы в скорости не будет. Правда есть одно замечание... Слабое место ArrayList  в том, что ему приходится пересоздавать массив для добавления новых элементов при превышении индекса заполняемости. Разумеется, это его замедляет.Однако, если вы делаете такой выбор , то значит вы знаете количество ваших цифр, которое вы хотите сохранить. В этом случае выбирайте ArrayList , но при создании в конструкторе передайте количество элементов - List  list - new ArrayList <>(80);, это ускорит его работу, т.к. избавит от необходимости пересоздания массива и копирования элементов, а ваш код благодаря использовании коллекции, а не массива, станет более гибким. 2.Выбор коллекции. Тут тоже все просто в пределах стандартной библиотеки. Вы смотрите либо в сторону Set, либо в сторону List. Причем из сетов вам подойдет лишь TreeSet. Плюс в том , что вы получите сортировку из коробки и не заморачиваясь. Минус - это все таки сет, тут все элементы уникальны. Если это условие не выполняется , то он вам никак не подходит и остается только лист. Если же условие выполняется, то TreeSet зарекомендует себя лучше на больших размерах коллекции, хотя не думаю, что разница во времени будет столь значительна. В этом случае я бы делал выбор, исходя из методов интерфейсов сет и лист, а не из скорости.

Comment: Вы скажите, что быстрее  и Arrays.sort или Collections.sort. И пожалуйста, прочтите ответ ниже.

Comment: Для этого есть оф.документация и сорцы. Тогда становится понятно, что сортировка листа более ресурсоемкоя операция, чем сортировка массива. Документация подтверждает. Collections.sort использует Arrays.sort плюс дополнительное использование памяти и времени.